# Unable to serialize the session state using stateserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I m getting following error and wondering if we can make System.Data.Linq.EntitySet serializable

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[[NES.HiLo.Data.DAO.UserResource, NES.HiLo.Data, Version=1.0.5012.39381, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.]
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +7738715
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +258
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +111
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +422
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter) +51
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +7636088
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +461
>      System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +134
>      System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1577

Answer (score 7):

The exception actually tells you already what the issue is, EntitySet is not serializeable. Therefore it cannot be stored in session state if you use the session DB feature.

EntitySet does not implement/support this. Therefore to store it in the session state, you would have to read the data into your own objects and then save it for example.
Or simply do not try to use session state to "persist" those kind of objects because usually you don't want to do this (no best practice).

Comment: So what is best practice for this kind of thing?

Comment: Implement your application stateless as good as you can prevents a lot of issues. Whenever you need user states or profile data, you could persist this in a database (dedicated tables) and load the data into memory. If needed you can use distributed memory caches to keep the data available for multiple web servers.

Answer (score 3):

One easiest & one of the best solution is to use `Json.NET` library.

This library allows you to do bidirectional transformation of `LINQ` objects to their `JSON` representation. 
For example, you can store the product in the view state , with just few lines of code:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
ViewState["product"] = json ;
```

and retrieve it back too :

```
product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(ViewState["product"] as string);
```

Refer these 2 links for more:

1.) http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

2.) http://www.codeplex.com/json/

if your application is using `in-process` state management, you'll be able to store LINQ objects in Session, Application and Cache. However you won't be able to store them in the view state.

The reason is that the data stored in the view state is serialized using a binary formatter.

Therefore one more solution is to make the `LINQ` class serializable, you'll need to mark all `System.Data.Linq.EntitySet` and `System.Data.Linq.EntityRef` fields with `NonSerialized` attribute and to mark with `Serializable` attribute the `LINQ` class.

And yet another solution is to manually extract data from the `LINQ` objects, store it to some intermediate format (`class`, `struct`,... etc.) and later manually transform it back.